# Automatically panning the map in ArcGIS when using the Time slider

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, gps, timeslider, video

I have a point dataset with time-stamps at 1 minute intervals showing a driving route.

I have enabled the Time properties of the layer and I am able to use the Time slider to see the points move along the route.

What I would like to do is to zoom in closer to the map so that I can't see the full extent of the route, and when I press the "play" button on the time slider, for the map to automatically pan with the point as it moves in time.

Is this possible using just the desktop functionality?

I am doing this on ArcInfo 10.1, but I could do it in ArcInfo 10.2.1 if there are new features on there.

I do also have a gps enabled time-stamped video of the same driving route if this makes the process any easier?  But I guess linking the video to the route in Arc is somethign for later!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want to do is possible using just desktop.  However, rather than using the Time Slider you will be using the Animation Toolbar tools to create a time animation track and a view capture track that play at the same time.  To stay completely within ArcMap, you will have to set key frames for the view (zoom level and position) and it will interpolate between them.  If you choose to move into ArcScene, you can actually set the camera up to follow a path.

Two places to start for more information/tutorials would be the ArcGIS 10.1 help section:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_an_animation/000900000001000000/

and a video presentation by ESRI on map animation (60 min.):

http://video.esri.com/watch/656/creating-animations